# Why does Object.create interfere with return value of Object.keys, Object.values & Object.entries?

Tags: javascript, object

In the simple test code below I use a factory function to instantiate an object.  When I examine its contents with `Object.keys`, `Object.values` & `Object.entries` it returns the values I expect.

```js
"use strict"
 
function testFunction(x, y) {
    return {
        firstKey: x,
        secondKey: y
        }
}

let testObject = testFunction('ONE', 'TWO');  //generic factory function

console.log(Object.keys(testObject));
console.log(Object.values(testObject));
console.log(Object.entries(testObject));
```

When I instantiate the object with `Object.assign` it also works as expected.

```js
"use strict"
 
function testFunction(x, y) {
    return {
        firstKey: x,
        secondKey: y
        }
}

let testObject = Object.assign(testFunction('ONE', 'TWO'));  //Object.assign test

console.log(Object.keys(testObject));
console.log(Object.values(testObject));
console.log(Object.entries(testObject));
```

However when I use `Object.create` to instantiate the object `Object.keys`, `Object.values` & `Object.entries` return empty arrays.  This is not what I expect.  **Why is this happening?**  Why does a generic factory function and `Object.assign` return the predicted value but `Object.create` does not?

```js
"use strict"
 
function testFunction(x, y) {
    return {
        firstKey: x,
        secondKey: y
        }
}

let testObject = Object.create(testFunction('ONE', 'TWO'));  //Object.create test

console.log(Object.keys(testObject));
console.log(Object.values(testObject));
console.log(Object.entries(testObject));
```

Comment: Because all of these return the keys/values of *own* properties, not inherited ones.